# What to bring for a 3-month work trip to Catalunya in winter?

Tags: luggage, tips-and-tricks, work, winter, long-term

I need to pack for a work trip in Spain and I will be away for 3/4 months with my husband and kids.

I am traveling by train so I can bring more luggage.

What should I bring? How is the temperature?

I was thinking about bringing 4 leggings of different colors that can match different shirts, several long sleeved shirts, 4 long cardigans of different colors, 2 pants, 2 casual dresses, 1 elegant dress, 2 suit jackets, 2 pajamas, all underwear and socks I own, stockings, 1 pair of boots, 1 pair of everyday city shoes, 1 pair of flat shoes, and one pair of high heels, slippers. Is this enough?

Then bathroom things (makeup, toothpaste, shampoo, hairdryer, etc), towels.

Medicines and supplements.

Notebook, telephone charger, adapter.

I am sure I am forgetting something crucial.

Is there anything else I should definitely bring with me? What was that you wished you had in your longer trips but you forgot? Any suggestion?

Comment: Toiletries such as toothpaste and supplements will be readily available in Catalunya, no need to load up on them IMHO

Comment: @Traveller yes I know, but I will make a stop in France and I still need to wash my teeth and take a shower during the trip :)

Comment: @AkiPhD, please edit with where you are from and what kind of temperatures are normal for you.

Comment: Do you plan to visit, or even live, in the Pyrenees? Not surprisingly it is colder there especially in Winter.

Comment: You might be interested in the average temperature for each month across Catalunya https://www.meteo.cat/wpweb/climatologia/el-clima/atles-climatic/ Note that the text is in Catalan but as long as you select the right month in the drop-down menu you should not need to read the rest.